# How to add default logback.xml to spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have created a new spring boot project using spring initializer with `spring-boot-starter-web` as a starter project.I am able to use logback for logging but am unable to find default logback.xml in the project.I tried to search out but could not find reference to default file on logback documentation as well. I am looking to customize the logback file to use custom appender.

Comment: See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can customize by using your application.yml, like this :

```
logging:
    level:
        root: WARN
        org.springframework.security: DEBUG
        org.springframework.web.servlet: INFO
        org.springframework.jmx: INFO
        org.springframework.cloud.config.client: INFO
        org.springframework.cloud.context: INFO
        org.hibernate: INFO       
        org.hibernate.sql: DEBUG
    pattern:
        console: '%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %-65logger - %msg%n'
        file: '%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %-65logger - %msg%n'
    file: D:/logs/my-log.log
```

And define for each profile